# Our system installed CentOS7.9 -> OK; install Ubunt 22.04 -> failed, why?

Tags: drivers, intel, amd-processor

Our system: AMD Genoa CPU + intel C627/QAT & LAN add-on cards

CentOS 7.9, Intel C627 add-on card works correctly:

[image: CentOS 7.9, Intel C627 add-on card works correctly]

Ubuntu 22.04 failed to work:

[image: Ubuntu 22.04 failed to work]

Does Ubuntu have special firmware for Intel C627?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! You will need to be more specific about the failure. Did you get any error messages. What indicates to you that it failed? When did the failure occur? We need more information to know what the problem is. Thanks.

Comment: Also be specific with details; Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server uses a different installer to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop, but you didn't mention which you're asking about. Some releases also have ISO choice, where each ISO uses a different installer. Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices, with the default set by ISO used for install, but you didn't mention (22.04 has ISOs using 5.15, 5.19 & 6.2 kernels for example, plus some OEM options; in case you're not familiar with significance; kernel modules are *drivers*).

Comment: 1. We didn't get error message.  We only got system hanged screen image.   2. Our OS is Ubuntu 22.04.1 desktop.  3. The kernel is 5.19.0-50.50-generic 5.19.17.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.1 Desktop used the 5.15 kernel, Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop used the 5.19 kernel (and .3 uses 6.2), so your last comments details don't make sense to me (22.04.1 & 5.19 don't align; are you sure you were using 22.04.1 and that wasn't a packaging detail). I'll suggest checking what you actually used.

Comment: We tried Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS.  Our system + intel C627/QAT & LAN add-on cards + i40e driver can boot up and C627 LAN ports can work correctly.  We tried Ubuntu 22.04.1 with the same test environment.  The system will hang and display "failed to start user login management".  Do Ubuntu 22.04.1 need other C627 driver?  Thank you for your help.

Comment: I would like to share the pictures; but, failed.  Can someone tell me how to do it?